# Error compiling Unity after porting to mac

Tags: unity, macos

I used BitBucket to move my project from a PC to a Mac, now I can't compile in my Mac, as I get the following error:

`Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='/Users/josephtripp/Library/Android/sdk/tools/aapt', CommandLine='package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "/Users/josephtripp/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-22/android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.everyplay.Everyplay:com.unity3d.ads.android -S "/Users/josephtripp/sens-rebooted/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/everyplay/res" -S "/Users/josephtripp/sens-rebooted/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res"', CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'`

Any help would be of great use.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using Android based on the error. Try reinstalling/installing the Java JDK and the Android SDK on your Mac. If that doesn't work make sure you install the 32-bit and 64-bit version of those libraries.

Also, make sure you are using the Mac SDK for Android when on Android, and the Windows SDK for Android only when on Windows.